# Wireless connection work fine on PC but on iPhone it shows "No internet connection"

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have Netgear N450 wireless gateway and I use wireless card on my PC to connect wirelessly. On my iPhone, however, I connect to the network but it shows "No internet connection".

Wifi used to be working on my phone, too but something happened so now I get this error message. 
I already restated gateway several times and reset through gateway control (192.168.xx)

Ideas?

Comment: Did you give your iPhone an invalid static IP address?

Comment: It's DHCP. Moreover, I had this problem couple of months ago but I don't remember how I solved it.

Comment: Did you try forgetting the network and rejoining? What kind of security does this network use? If it's still on old insecure WEP for some reason, clients can't tell when they get the password wrong, so they join the network but can't get a DHCP lease.